# JSON variable not retrieving updated value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, twitter

I am trying to post a quote retrieved from a JSON file. My code posts a tweet every 20 seconds (for testing purposes it is 20 seconds). I can find my quote and put it in a JSON file by using the `server(quoteIndex)` function. The `server(quoteIndex)` adds a new quote to my `output.json` file. I know that `output.json` updates the `{"quote": ""}` part each time it finds a quote on an even index. However, in my `tweetIt()` function, when I assign `var quoteFile = require("./output.json")`, my `quoteFile.quote` value does not update. This is an issue because my javascript bot is a twitter bot that tweets quotes. And twitter does not allow duplicate quotes, handing me a "duplicate status" error.

**This is the main code**

```
// I wanted to start at the 8th index and continue with every even index.
 var quoteIndex = 8;

 // post a tweet every 20 seconds
 setInterval(tweetIt, 1000*20);
```

**tweetIt()**

```
function tweetIt() {
    //
    // This will start looking for quotes to post
    // It will put the quote in a JSON file
    //
    quoteIndex = quoteIndex + 2;
    console.log('value of index: ' + quoteIndex)
    server(quoteIndex);

    var js = require('json-update');
    js.load('./output.json', function(err, obj) {
    console.log("Loaded from json:");
    console.log(obj);                 // loads most recent quote
    });                               // this is what I want to tweet


    var quoteFile = require('./output.json');

    // Read from JSON file for the quote
    var params = {
        status: quoteFile.quote       
    }                                

    //
    // prints same quote each time, does not update
    //
    console.log("quote to tweet: " + quoteFile.quote) 

    //  tweet a quote
    //
    // The first quote will tweet, however when the JSON file
    // updates, I will get a "duplicate status" error.
    // This is because my quoteFile still has not updated.
    // 
    T.post('statuses/update', params, getData);
    function getData(err, data, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Something went wrong!: " + err);
        } else {
            console.log("Tweeted something!");
        }
    }
}
```

**server(quoteNumber)**

```
function server(quoteNumber) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var request = require("request"),
    cheerio = require("cheerio"),
    url = "https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/A_Song_of_Ice_and_Fire";


    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);

        var quote;
        var json = {quote : ""};

        $( "div.mw-parser-output ul" ).filter(function( INDEX ) {

            // even indexed quotes are the ones I want
            if (INDEX % 2 == 0 && (INDEX == quoteNumber)) {
              quote = $( this ).text();   
              json.quote = quote;      // this also has the most recent quote
             }
        });
      } else {
        console.log("We’ve encountered an error: " + error);
      }

  //
  // Write our quotes out to a JSON file.
  //
  fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(json, null, 4).replace(/\\n/g, " "), function(err){
    console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.json file');
  })
});
```

Basically, when I run the code using node.js, the first quote will tweet because the JSON file has a quote for me. Then when it is time to find the next quote using `quoteIndex = quoteIndex + 2`, my JSON file updates as expected in my project folder. My main issues is that in my `tweetIt()` function, the `quoteFile.quote` is not showing the updated quote, even though the JSON file has an updated quote for me. How can I have the updated quote?

Any tips would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you `require()` a file, be it a module or JSON file or native addon, it is cached once it is successfully loaded. If you need to be able to reload the JSON file, you should instead just call `readFile()` and `JSON.parse()` the resulting file data  manually each time.

Comment: I am confused on how I would go about implementing `readFile()`. I could go about going it by doing `fs.readFile('./output.json', ...)` but everything inside of that (the quote data), I would not be able to assign to my `params` variable.

Comment: Sure you could, just put all of the logic below the `readFile()` call inside the callback. If you want to stick with synchronous calls, then use `readFileSync()`.